# UnicodeDecodeError when using paramiko.py3compat.decodebytes

Tags: python-3.x, sftp

I got following error when using decodebyes.
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte`

```
import pysftp
import paramiko
from paramiko.py3compat import decodebytes

keydata = b"""4049a539f13cba06a874c4b6aadd0cc4"""

key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add('xxx.www.it', 'ssh-rsa', key)

with pysftp.Connection('xxx.www.it', username='google', password='xxx', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.get('remote_file')
```

I am using python 3.5.

This is a Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
  File "/home/asd/workstation/Python/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 65, in __init__
    cert_type="ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com",
  File "/home/asd/workstation/Python/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 397, in _check_type_and_load_cert
    type_ = msg.get_text()
  File "/home/asd/workstation/Python/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/message.py", line 178, in get_text
    return u(self.get_string())
  File "/home/asd/workstation/Python/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/py3compat.py", line 156, in u
    return s.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: What is a traceback of the exception? I'm actually getting a different error: "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t" (though I'm on Python 3.6.3).

Comment: Do you need hosting url and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an issue.There is a problem on your keydata. "4049a539f13cba06a874c4b6aadd0cc4" is not a RSA.

To create a RSA key, use following commands:

`ssh-keyscan xxx.www.it ssh-rsa 4049a539f13cba06a874c4b6aadd0cc4`